# Passing a dictionary and searching a set of values and returning another dictionary in haskell

Tags: haskell, dictionary

I was writing a code that accepts a `dictionary` and a `array of keys` and check the dictionary and see if that key is in the dictionary or not, if it is not there leave it, else send back the dictionary of those keys and values whose keys are in the dictionary

I wore the code but i am getting too many errors

```
let x = check dict key
putStrLn $ show (x)

check :: Eq k => [(k, v)] ->[k] -> [(k,v)]
check dict words = [findVal word dict | word <- words]

findVal :: (Eq k) => k -> [(k,v)] -> [(k, v)]
findVal key xs = foldr (\(k,v) acc -> case key == k of True -> (k,v)
                                                       False ->   acc) xs
```

The errors are that the data type of 2 functions and ever the cse is also an error

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each word in `words`, you want to find out in `dict` all these entries that their first part equals that word.

This can be implemented directly with list comprehension, using `words` and `dict` as generators, current word equals first part of pair as guard:

```
check dict words = [ e | key <- words, e@(k, _) <- dict, key == k ]
```

The following example demonstrates how that double generator list comprehension works:

```
> [(a, b) | a <- "abc", b <- [1..5]]
[('a',1),('a',2),('a',3),('a',4),('a',5),('b',1),('b',2),('b',3),('b',4),('b',5),('c',1),('c',2),('c',3),('c',4),('c',5)]
```

and shows why it is exactly what you need.

Answer (score 1):

```
\(k,v) acc -> case key == k of True -> (k,v)
                               False -> acc
```

What is the type of this function?

```
foldr (...) xs
```

How many parameters does `foldr` need?